# Convert a relational data frame into indicator variables

Tags: r, dataframe, relational, indicator

I have a relational data frame with 2 columns, customers and purchases. I would like a data frame with a row for each distinct customer and a column for each product with indicators variable showing whether or not that customer has purchased that product.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(customer=c("A", "A", "B", "B"), purchase = c("Milk", "Eggs", "Juice", "Milk"))
  customer purchase
1        A     Milk
2        A     Eggs
3        B    Juice
4        B     Milk
```

I want:

```
  customer Milk Eggs Juice
1        A    1    1     0
2        B    1    0     1
```

Comment: Just use `table(df)`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's all I needed

Comment: The answer at the linked question shows what to do when combinations are more than one, thus giving you an actual set of indicator variables rather than tabulated results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, customer~purchase, length, value.var='purchase')
#    customer Eggs Juice Milk
#1        A    1     0    1
#2        B    0     1    1
```